# FTP client and password storage

Tags: windows, ftp

Since we noticed that some user on our internal network use FTP client like FileZilla or WinSCP that store password as plain text, we wonder, is there any FTP client (windows) that store passwords in a "secure" way?

## Edit

Also, we know that could use cerificate and SSH methods, but question is only about password storage.

Answer (score 0):

For SCP/SFTP method there is [Bitvise Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) that encrypt the password on the profile

Answer (score 0):

[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/download.htm)

It does not store password as FileZilla does but is considered to be more "secure".

Comment: And that was our first idea .....

Comment: @DonCallisto You can read more about it in this [blog post](http://www.vanachteren.net/2006/07/24/crack-total-commander-ftp-password/)

Answer (score 0):

WinSCP does not save passwords in plain text.

Though obviously it can only "obfuscate" the password. It is not possible to securely encrypt passwords in a way that still allows for automatic use.
Read about [Security of credentials](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/security_credentials).

For better security, you can enable [password encryption using master password](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/master_password).